# Wordpress - Problem with regenerated thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently added some new image sizes via. my functions.php. As I have approximately 300 images uploaded, I used the plugin Regenerate Thumbails (https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to bulk regenerate thumbnail sizes for all my images.

It all seemed to work perfectly well, as my /wp-content/uploads/ folder now have all the thumbnails generated in the correct sizes.

The problem occurs when I try to use the sizes on the frontend though. I had previously used the default image sizes without a problem, but after regeneration the image IS loaded but it is the full size one, not the thumbnail. The same thing happens when I try to use my new image sizes.

I have searched for an answer for hours now, and I couldn't find anything.

Thing I've tried:

Using another plugin (AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild) to regenerate

Using both ['sizes'] and get_wp_attachment on frontend

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please ask your question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In functions.php, you would want to add the following to add a new image size:

```
add_image_size('my-featured-image', 800, 400, true);
```

Once the above has been added to your theme functions.php file, any image uploaded (after `adding add_image_size()`) that meets the x and y pixel value minimums will be resized accordingly, and then cropped. Otherwise, images before adding `add_image_size()` will need to be processed either using the plugin the OP mentioned, or using the wp-cli tool.

Next, to use your image, add the following in the appropriate theme/template file:

```
the_post_thumbnail('my-featured-image');
```

If the image being used does not meet the x and y values mentioned above, then the `add_image_size()` will not be used, and instead the original non-modified image will be used.

More information on the use of `add_image_size()` can be found here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

```
add_image_size( string $name, int $width, int $height, bool|array $crop = false )
```

The value `true` used for the 4th parameter, `$crop`, is as the param says. If you don't want cropping to take place, set the value to `false`. Please review the provided reference for all possible options, such as how to crop by position and so on.

Comment: Thing is, I've already done all of that. The problem is not registering the image sizes or displaying them, the problem is that running the regenerate plugin broke my Wordpress in some way, and now it can't find those image sizes even though they are on the server (Have checked via. FTP)

Comment: Are the images appearing in your media library in WP?

Comment: They are. Just found out that new uploaded images work perfectly fine with image sizes. So it must the plugin that broke the functionality.